# Which Linux system for Tezos?

Tags: baking, node, linux

Has there a preference emerged amongst people running a node/bakers for a type of Linux system? I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04. My friend is running Fedora. Is there any advantage in using either of the two? What are people using? Any preference? If yes, why?

Comment: The answer to this question will be subjective. See https://tezos.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer to this question will be subjective

Comment: The question is off-topic because it is only incidentally related to Tezos, like "what music do you listen to while using Tezos?" (but less extreme). It is also primarily opinion-based, incidentally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned any answers will be subjective and it really doesn't matter which Linux you choose.

I would suggest either using the Tezos docker image for this and then it really doesn't matter, or look at the linux distro the team choose for their Dockerfile and use that as your base distro. You certainly couldn't go wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a GUI version of linux i suggest lubuntu.  Its very light weight and I find it great for VNC / RDP as it has no animations etc compared to ubuntu.